# Headphone jack not detected

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I've been working on this for a while, and I haven't really gotten anywhere.

I have an MSI GS60 Ghost Pro (Skylake), which comes with the Realtek ALC898 chipset for audio.

What's a little strange about this computer is that it has four speakers: two large front ones, and two small rear ones (they're technically separate lines). The problem is that, in Linux, the headphones seem to be tied directly to the rear speaker line.

The headphones also aren't detected in alsamixer, pavucontrol or kmix.

I've used `hdajackretask` to force-enable anything I can set to be a headphone output, and if I have my audio profile set to `Analog Stereo Duplex`, apps *do* see the headphone jack, but it's always "unplugged," so auto switching doesn't work.

In the 4.0 Surround profile, this workaround has no effect, but it's how I found out that the headphone jack is mirroring the rear channel.

I've tried playing around with pulseaudio configs and switches, and I've tried clearing those configs and resetting. I've tried installing the official Realtek drivers, but since they're from 2014, they don't compile.

This is Ubuntu 18.04, but the same problem exists on 17.10 and 17.04.

Here is some info (tell me what else to run):

```
$ lspci | grep Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
```

---

```
$ pacmd list-cards
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 6
        properties:
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdd120000 irq 135"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "a170"
                device.product.name = "Sunrise Point-H HD Audio"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "0"
                device.description = "Built-in Audio"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        profiles:
                input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: unknown)
                output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
                output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
                output:analog-surround-21: Analog Surround 2.1 Output (priority 800, available: unknown)
                output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 860, available: unknown)
                output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Output (priority 700, available: unknown)
                output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 760, available: unknown)
                output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 5500, available: unknown)
                output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5560, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5460, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 360, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 360, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra4+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra4+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra4+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
                off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
        active profile: <output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo>
        sinks:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-surround-40/#0: Built-in Audio Analog Surround 4.0
        sources:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-surround-40.monitor/#0: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Surround 4.0
                alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo/#1: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
        ports:
                analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
                analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
                iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:

                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

---

```
$ sudo hdajacksensetest 
Pin 0x18 (Black Mic, Rear side): present = No
```

Comment: In `hdajackretask` what happens if you set the headphone "Connectivity" to "jack" and "Jack detection" to "present" in the "Advanced override"?

Comment: And what does `hdajacksensetest` show after that?

Comment: If I override every output I can to Headphones and set the jack detection and all that, the `hdajacksensetest` shows all of them, but none are ever connected. @stumblebee